# Remove spacing table inside table

Tags: html, css

i want to remove space between table, heres my code

```
<table class="table table-striped-column" border="2" style="border-color: #0082AD">
                <tr>
                    <th>Icon</th>
                    <th style="width:65%; text-align:left">Football Forums</th>
                    <th>Topics</th>
                    <th>Posts</th>
                    <th style="width:35%">Last Post</th>
                </tr>
                <!--INSERT DATA-->
                <tr>
                    <td>Icon</td>
                    <td>
                        <table border="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td>link</td>
                                <td>view</td>
                                <td>image</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="font-size:10px">ket</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="font-size:10px">sponsored</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

i hve tried using margin 0 and padding 0, i also tried using cellpadding n cellspacing but its not working at all

and i want to remove this

[image: TABLE INSIDE TABLE]

Answer (score 0):

You have a margin set on the table. Clear it on the nested tables using:

```
td table {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Also, the `border`, `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` attributes are deprecated (since a long time). You should use CSS for that.

Answer (score 0):

The second table is like text inside fist table cell and it has padding. You have to set padding to 0 of a td that is around the second table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <table>
        <!-- second table data -->
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, if you have a border around the second table and you want to collapse it with td around it you have to reduce margins to size of border thickness, e.g. for 1px border:

```
<!-- second table -->
<table style="margin-top: -1px; margin-left: -1px;">
```